# How I can bind property, which use another static property

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I use mvvm pattern in my progeсt (C#), and I have some problem.
I have a label on my view, and label's text is binded to property from my viewModel:

```
val label=new Label();
label.SetBinding<StatusViewModel>(Label.TextProperty, x=>x.TextProp);
```

this is my view model, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
class StatusViewModel
{
private string _textProp;
public string TextProp
{
   get
   {
      return _textProp;
   }
   set
   {
      if(_textProp == value)
        return _textProp;

      _textProp=value;
      OnPropertyChange();
   }
}
}
```

but I have another static property:

```
static class StaticClass
{
public static string StaticText {get; set; }
}
```

And I want use this static property StaticText inside my TextProp property from StatusViewModel. And StaticText property mast notify label about it changes.

P.S. sorry about possible mistakes, I typed this code from my head.

Comment: You've got a return statement in a setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding to `static` properties, you are probably doing it wrong :)

That said, the initial bind is super easy. You just need to add a property that returns the `static` one:

```
public string StaticTextRedirect
{
   get { return StaticClass.StaticText; }
   set { StaticClass.StaticText = value; }
}
```

The `PropertyChanged` event is another beast. You could raise it from the `StaticTextRedirect` property of course, but that won't fire if some *other* class changes the property. You'll probably need to just raise a custom event in the static property's setter that client code can listen to and raise the appropriate `PropertyChanged` event for.

Comment: I try also extends StaticClass from INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but I can't use OnPropertyChange inside static property (and I think it's not what you say). Can you please provide me a some example?

Comment: @Brian That wouldn't work anyways, the static class is not your data context, nor the context for the static property. You need to raise a *custom* event (your own) that the VM listens for, then raises its own `PropertyChanged`. Does that make sense? If it sounds like a lot of hassle, it is. You shouldn't be binding to static properties :)

Comment: so, if create my own event in StaticClass and raise it in StaticText's setter, then subscribe to this event in StatusViewModel and execute OnPropertyChange("TextProp") when event raises, it wiil be work?

Comment: In my example it would be `OnPropertyChange("StaticTextRedirect")`, but other than that. Yes, that should work.